Less than vs less than of
I came across a grammatical structure that struck me as a little weird in the next lines

By a continuing process of inflation, governments can confiscate, secretly and unobserved, an important part of the wealth of their citizens. By this method, they not only confiscate, but they confiscate arbitrarily; and, while the process impoverishes many, it actually enriches some. The sight of this arbitrary rearrangement of riches strikes not only at security, but at confidence in the equity of the existing distribution of wealth. Those to whom the system brings windfalls . . . become ‘profiteers’, who are the object of the hatred of the bourgeoisie, whom the inflationism has impoverished not less than of the proletariat. As the inflation proceeds . . . all permanent relations between debtors and creditors, which form the ultimate foundation of capitalism, become so utterly disordered as to be almost meaningless . . .62

Ferguson, Niall. The Ascent of Money: A Financial History of the World: 10th Anniversary Edition (English Edition) (p. 99). Penguin Publishing Group. Edición de Kindle.
I suppose that because he is using the preposition "of" he is saying that the profiteers are the object of hatred for both the bourgeoisie and the proletariat, being that if he were using "not less than of" just the same as "not less than the proletariat" then, I could not understand why he is using the preposition "of". I would have rephrased the whole paragraph like this:

Those to whom the system brings windfalls . . . become ‘profiteers’, who are the object of the hatred of the bourgeoisie, not less than of the proletariat whom the inflationism has impoverished.

As inflation impoverished both the bourgeoisie and the proletariat. The way he phrased it I find it weird.

I think there's a missing comma after "impoverished". That makes "whom the inflationism has impoverished" a parenthetical, and then the whole sentence makes sense.

You've also added a double quote after "proletariet" in your rephrasing. That seems like a typo.

The guy writes really well. Are  you  planning to go through the entire book? It's a skipped word: not less than that of the proletariat" But you should post the whole sentence.

@Lambie Yes, I will go through the entire book , as I am having financial difficulties. I think that would be the whole sentence.

Please post the full sentence. It's a long sentence. It's a comparative but we need the whole thing.

@Lambie Ready, Thank you!

The book is great for understanding what capitalism actually does but won't help you directly with your financial troubles...

@Lambie Have you got any recommendations by any chance?

There are many sites in the States that provide guidance; just be careful in choosing a good one, not a scam one or paying one.

quiqui: try this site: https://upsolve.org/

It is not an error of editing or grammar. The way to parse the noun phrase is as the object of A not less than [the object] of B. The construction is analogous to that of I have bottles of red wine and of white. It’s not common—especially in contemporary casual speech—but neither is it at all incorrect.
And in a sentence like The shelves are stacked with packages of salt and [of] pepper, the presence or absence of the of affects the meaning. Without the of, the sentence is likely to mean that each package contains both salt and pepper; with the of it means that some of the packages contain salt while others contain pepper.

Those to whom the system brings windfalls . . . become ‘profiteers’, who are the object of the hatred of the bourgeoisie, whom the inflationism has impoverished not less than of the proletariat.
This is an editing issue; not a grammar issue. If you remove "of", it is grammatical.
Inflationism has impoverished the bourgeosie not less than the proletariat.
It is to be expected that a long, complicated text will have some detail that has escaped the copyeditor's attention. It happens.

Thank you very much!

@Quique My cat is Coco, and I always ask her when I pick her up: Are you my quiqui? Funny, huh?

It is the hypocoristic of my first name Enrique but that's true, they do look similar.
